# Angular 6 errors when running ng serve - Emitted value instead of an instance of Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a project that was working just fine and I am thinking that I ran an update and that has caused an error that I am erperiencing.

```
$ ng serve
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open 

your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2018-09-13T00:04:59.389Z
Hash: dd4fca7dc10f51a75e42
Time: 22214ms
chunk {children-children-module} children-children-module.js, children-children-module.js.map (children-children-module) 99.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {children-children-module~home-home-module~ucp-list-v1-list-module~ucp-ucp-module} children-children-module~home-home-module~ucp-list-v1-list-module~ucp-ucp-module.js, children-children-module~home-home-module~ucp-list-v1-list-module~ucp-ucp-module.js.map (children-children-module~home-home-module~ucp-list-v1-list-module~ucp-ucp-module) 171 kB  [rendered]
chunk {error-error-module} error-error-module.js, error-error-module.js.map (error-error-module) 15.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module.js, home-home-module.js.map (home-home-module) 7.67 kB  [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 83.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 415 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 8.4 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 778 kB  [rendered]
chunk {session-session-module} session-session-module.js, session-session-module.js.map (session-session-module) 29.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 819 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {ucp-list-v1-list-module} ucp-list-v1-list-module.js, ucp-list-v1-list-module.js.map (ucp-list-v1-list-module) 7.69 kB  [rendered]
chunk {ucp-ucp-module} ucp-ucp-module.js, ucp-ucp-module.js.map (ucp-ucp-module) 7.57 kB  [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 8.84 MB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss/components/_wheather.scss:2:4: Can't read file '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/img/wheather.jpg', ignoring

WARNING in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss/utilities/_base.scss:262:4: Can't read file '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/img/6.jpg', ignoring

WARNING in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss/utilities/_base.scss:267:4: Can't read file '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/img/7.jpg', ignoring

ERROR in ./src/assets/climacon/climacon-font/styles.css (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/assets/climacon/climacon-font/styles.css)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/climacon/climacon-font/styles.css:5:8: Can't resolve 'climacons-webfont.svg' in '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/climacon/climacon-font'

  3 |   src:url('climacons-webfont.eot');
  4 |   src:url('climacons-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
> 5 |           url('climacons-webfont.svg#Climacons-Font') format('svg'),
    |                ^
  6 |           url('climacons-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  7 |           url('climacons-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

ERROR in ./src/assets/glyphicons/glyphicons.css (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/assets/glyphicons/glyphicons.css)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/glyphicons/glyphicons.css:5:289: Can't resolve 'fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg' in '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/glyphicons'

  3 |
  4 |   src: url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
> 5 |   src: url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
    |                                                                                                          ^
  6 | }
  7 | .glyphicon {

ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss/components/_wheather.scss:2:16: Can't resolve '../img/wheather.jpg' in '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss'

  1 | .wheather-widget {
> 2 |     background: url(../img/wheather.jpg);
    |                ^
  3 |     background-repeat: no-repeat;
  4 |     background-size: cover;

ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss/utilities/_base.scss:262:16: Can't resolve '../img/6.jpg' in '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss'

  260 |
  261 | .form-bg {
> 262 |     background: url(../img/6.jpg);
      |                ^
  263 |     background-size: cover;
  264 | }

ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss/utilities/_base.scss:267:16: Can't resolve '../img/7.jpg' in '/Users/user123/Angular/Project123/src/assets/scss'

  265 |
  266 | .error-bg {
> 267 |     background: url(../img/7.jpg);
      |                ^
  268 |     background-size: cover;
  269 |     height: 100vh;

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I don't even know where to start to debug this. I am using a seed project template I purchased so it's probably from a dependency being used in there but I am not sure if its a library issue or something with my environment?

Comment: It looks like its looking for background images and/or SVG's in the CSS/SCSS files in the assets folder which do not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all dependencies of images and SVG files that do not exist or point to a non-existing directory, specifically in `.css` or `.scss` files, specifically the `styles.scss` file